# ProgressDialog in Notification

Tags: android, progressdialog

I've been trying to put a ProgressDialog inside my custom notification layout. It's not working, since ProgressDialog's can not be created inside an XML. Therefore, I'm asking here for help.

How should I be able to implement the ProgressDialog in my custom layout?

I have looked [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html), but that doesn't explain how I would go if I want the ProgressDialog inside a custom layout.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you need a [ProgressBar widget](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) not a dialog.